# SVG crash Safari

Tags: svg, safari, crash, svg-filters

I'm working on a portfolio ([http://www.chloémorillon.com/](http://chlo%C3%A9morillon.com/)) website and I've got a problem when I checked it throught all the web browsers. It work well on chrome, but when I check it with Safari, the browser keep refreshing the page until it crash definitely.

I use SVG to render the parallepipeds so I think that the problem come from there...

Here's the code for each shaped box :

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="485" width="305" class="svg-graphic">
         <filter id="grayscale">
              <feColorMatrix values="0" type="saturate"/>
         </filter>
         <g>
         <clipPath id="hex-mask">
         <polygon points="200, 0  200,284 0,384  0, 100"/>
         </clipPath>
         </g>
         <a xlink:href="http://xn--chlomorillon-eeb.com/projets/">
         <polygon transform="translate(2, 6)" points="200, 0  200,284 0,384  0, 100" stroke-width="10" stroke="#1a171b" fill="#1a171b"/>
         <polygon transform="translate(2, 6)" points="200, 0  200,284 0,384  0, 100" stroke-width="10" stroke="#75ffba" fill="#75ffba" id="bandw"/>
         <image preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice" transform="translate(3, 6)" xlink:href="http://xn--chlomorillon-eeb.com/wp-content/themes/culotte/images/accueil1.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" clip-path="url(#hex-mask)" id="color"/>
        <image preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice" transform="translate(3, 6)" xlink:href="http://xn--chlomorillon-eeb.com/wp-content/themes/culotte/images/accueil1.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" filter="url(#grayscale)" clip-path="url(#hex-mask)" id="bandw"/>
         </a>
     </svg>
```

Do you have any clue about my problem ?

Comment: It works fine for me in Safari 6.0.2 under OS X 10.8.2.

Comment: The problem seems to appear on Safari < 6

Comment: Filters only work in Safari 6+

Comment: I get the same issue with Safari < 6. Even without filters. Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Just some general debugging help: when things fail try removing code until you find the offending piece of code. I'd start by removing the filter, since Safari 5 does not support SVG filters. This should not cause a crash (it should just ignore the filter) but you never know.

Another possible failure point is the utf-8 domain `http://xn--chlomorillon-eeb.com`, try a relative path (just `<a xlink:href="/projets">`).

Once you identify the piece of code that is causing the crash you can devise a workaround, either with javascript or a fallback for Safari 5.